# How can I draw an arrow in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8

I want to draw an arrow in a cell on an excel sheet. My data is in the data frame and I would like to insert an arrow at a given cell (row, column) and then finally insert that in the excel or CSV sheet.

I thought of including UTF-8 value but couldn't get the output in normal Python shell. For instance, I found out that the utf-8 value for left arrow is `U+2190` and I performed the following but could not get the arrow printed:

```
>>> a = 'U+2190'.encode('utf-8')
>>> a
b'U+2190'
```

Since I am unable to deduce how to get the corresponding character from the utf-8, I am unable to decide how to get it in the dataframe and get it printed.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([['\u2190']])`

Comment: This is more Pythonic. Can you answer this so that I can accept it? My [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512532/10834788) is not as direct as yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Unicode escape](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)

```
pd.DataFrame([['\u2190']])

   0
0  ←
'2190'
```

Answer (score 0):

After referencing from [here](https://gist.github.com/rhunter/1122795), I was able to insert an arrow in the dataframe just like any other value:

```
df.at[prev_class_row_counter+1, 'Dependents'] = "➜"
```

Comment: This is not the best or stable solution. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512634/10834788) for the direct approach.